# Android AlertDialog Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

I have an alertdialog that I show but no matter what I do the alertdialog shows with a blank Title and Message.
The Icon, the Positive button and negative buttons show ok with correct descriptions.
Here is the snippets of code that I use:
In the Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="5"
android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

In my code I declare:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```

I also declare context:

```
final Context context = this;
```

I place my alert in :

```
public void confirm() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // set title

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("This is title");
        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("This is the message")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();



    // show it
            alertDialog.show();


}
```

I then call confirm from where I need it, like so:

```
confirm();
```

The alert shows up ok. 
The icon is set
The setPositiveButton is good and contains correct description
The setNegativeButton is good and contains correct description

The Title is blank
The Message is blank

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! A couple of tips: you can probably significantly reduce the length of your code snippet (the positive and negative messages are not really relevant to the Q). Also use the question title to summarise your question (e.g. "How do I set the AlertDialog title and message?").

Comment: Thanks bacar. However It is not a question of "how to set AlertDialog title and message" I have them working well in other classes. It is a question of why under a ListActivity they(Title & Message) fail to appear, while all the other elements (PositiveButton, NegativeButton, Icon) do appear.

Comment: Sure, it was just an example. BTW I couldn't possibly know those facts given what you have asked. Extra clarity is worthwhile - the title should be a brief, expressive summary of the question, not a set of topics/themes - that's what labels are for. Secondly you reveal in your comment that you have it working in a similar but different example. You should edit your Q body to include this, and say what differs (`ListActivity`). See [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: Thanks again bacar. Should get better with experience!! ;-)

Comment: Is there any chance that the title is set but you cant see it due to font colors set in your theme?

Answer (score 5):

you` can use

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Modify Customer Details");
```

OR

```
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Payment Options");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the message and title this way. This from the [developer's guide on Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics

```
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
```

// 3. Get the `AlertDialog` from `create()`

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: More info at hand. AlertDialog works when the class extends Activity. It is only when it extends ListActivity that the AlertDialog has problems. Certainly it must have something to do with the Context. However keep in mind the AlertDialog does appear, the icon appears, the buttons are correct. It is only the Message and Title that are blank. I tried to inflate a subview from within the class and display the AlertDialog from within this but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to your theme within context("this").you need check this context.
or you should inflate your own view,and call setView to place it in.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `alertDialog` creation line to:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```